# SQL UPDATE SET = subquery set (random)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to to the following (this is pseudo-code):

```
UPDATE Cars SET Engine = (SELECT EngineName FROM Engines WHERE Type = 3)[RANDOMIZE_INDEX_FROM_1_TO_SUBQUERY_COUNT]
```

So I basically need to `update` all `Cars table` with the random Engines from the **subquery**. Is this possible in `MSSQL`?

Comment: Do you want all cars to have different engines?

Comment: no, they can duplicate but they must be randomized. I will check Praveen answer soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Common Table Expression to give your Engine query row numbers and then select a random row number.

Assuming you have 100 engines - the query will go like this:

```
;with CTE as (
   SELECT EngineName, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by EngineName) as rn
   FROM Engines WHERE Type = 3
)
UPDATE Cars SET Engine = (SELECT EngineName FROM CTE WHERE where rn = 1+CAST(rand()*100 as int))
```

UPDATE: For any count of engines

```
;with CTE as (
   SELECT EngineName, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by EngineName) as rn
   FROM Engines WHERE Type = 3
)
UPDATE Cars SET Engine = (SELECT EngineName FROM CTE WHERE where rn = 1+CAST(rand()*(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CTE) as int))
```

UPDATE 2: Multirow update (Assuming Cars table has ID field or any other field you can sort on)

```
;WITH CTE_CARS AS (SELECT ENGINE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN FROM CARS)
,CTE_ENGINES AS (SELECT EngineName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RN FROM Engines WHERE Type = 3)
UPDATE CTE_CARS SET CTE_CARS.ENGINE = CTE_ENGINES.EngineName
FROM CTE_CARS JOIN CTE_ENGINES ON CTE_CARS.RN = CTE_ENGINES.RN
```

UPDATE 3: For cases where there're more Cars than enginges replace the last FROM with

```
FROM CTE_CARS JOIN CTE_ENGINES ON (CTE_CARS.RN - CTE_ENGINES.RN) % (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CTE_ENGINES) = 0
```

Comment: What if I don't have fixed Engines count (100)? They may change

Comment: @user2441297 does this have to be a one-liner? If not you can run another query prior to this one to get count of Engines

Comment: I would prefer a one-liner (I am using this query in ASP.NET parser.ExecuteNonQuery())

Comment: But if you are using executeNonQuery, then build a query and generate a random from Asp Net Code (there are functions that do it), and concatenate this with the query.

Comment: @user2441297 Updated for any count

Comment: Well, this is still not the answer. With this query I get randomized EngineName and this ONE EngineName is set to all cars. But I need different engine names to cars

Comment: THAT is a whole another story.

Comment: If you have some ideas for the answer, please help

Comment: I have a column in this table 'Id' which is int. I think it may help

Comment: Updated query for multiple updates, assuming CARS table has ID column

Comment: It almost works: there is just one problem. When my Cars table has 100 records, and the subquery produces 60 records, only 60 records from Cars table are updated